# Java - Swing form appear empty when get called

Tags: java, swing

I got a mouse click event that call and display a new JFrame form when click. But when I click, the form show up with no element inside it. There are 2 events of that type in my project and I handle them both with the same mechanism. The first one works perfectly, but the second one got the problem. I also use pack() but the problem is still there. Could any one show me how to work this out? Thanks a lot! My project is in Vietnamese, so if any one wants to mention any element in the code or the UI, just writing it with no sign is good enough!

Here are the event handlers:

```
//The first event

private void tblClientResultMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) tblClientResult.getModel();
    int row = tblClientResult.getSelectedRow();
    int col = tblClientResult.getSelectedColumn();

    if (col == 7) {
        SearchTruyenFrm searchTruyenFrm = new SearchTruyenFrm(listKH.get(row));
        searchTruyenFrm.setVisible(true);
    }
}


//The second one

private void tblTruyenResultMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) tblTruyenResult.getModel();
    int row = tblTruyenResult.getSelectedRow();
    int col = tblTruyenResult.getSelectedColumn();

    if (col == 6) {
        MuonTruyen muonTruyen = new MuonTruyen();
        muonTruyen.setTruyen(listTruyen.get(row));
        muonTruyen.setPhieuMuon(phieuMuon);

        //Trouble here (?)
        ThueTruyenInfoFrm infoFrm = new ThueTruyenInfoFrm(listTruyen.get(row));
        infoFrm.setVisible(true);

        while (infoFrm.isVisible()) {

        }

        muonTruyen.setDieuKien(infoFrm.getTxtDieuKien().getText());
        muonTruyen.setGiaMuon(Float.parseFloat(infoFrm.getTxtGiaThue().getText()));
        muonTruyen.setTienPhat(0);
        muonTruyen.setPaid(false);
    }
}
```

Inside the constructor:

```
public ThueTruyenInfoFrm(Truyen selected) {
    initComponents();

    txtTenTr.setText(selected.getTen());
    txtTacGia.setText(selected.getTacGia());
    pack();
}
```

How it happens:
[image: how the trouble goes]

Desired outcome:
[image]

Comment: This looks a bit busy `while (infoFrm.isVisible()) {

        }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat because I want the event to go on when the invoked form is no longer visible

Comment: Yeah but this is going to loop wildly consuming 100% of your CPU - maybe why the form never displays - consider adding a 100ms sleep in the loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've added `Thread.sleep(100)` but still doesn't work

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of "Honey, I've blocked the Event Dispatching Thread (and now nothing works)"

Mouse events (like all GUI based events) are delivered within the context of the EDT, so doing something like...

```
private void tblTruyenResultMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
   //....
   while (infoFrm.isVisible()) {
   }
}
```

will block the EDT and prevent any further processing of events, including paint events, basically hanging your program.

I suggest you start by having a read of [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to get a nutter understand of the overall issue.

To solve your problem, you will want to make use of a modal dialog, which will wait at the point the dialog is made visible and continue executing after it's closed.

Have a look at [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

This is an important lesson, as you should never start with a top level container (like `JFrame`), but instead, base all you GUIs on something like a `JPanel` instead, this gives you greater freedom in deciding on when and how those components are displayed.

Form editors won't teach you techniques which produce re-usable or self contained code and I would highly recommend that you consider spending sometime coding them by hand.

Comment: Was waiting for @MadProgrammer to replace my very wild speculation with facts

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ah, but you were doing such a great job 